# Slide out entire activity to reveal parent activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I am trying to design an Android app that has a settings activity/fragment. The main activity has a navigation drawer layout. I implemented the SettingsActivity using PreferenceFragment and an xml layout with PreferenceScreen.

I really want have have the settings activity in a card style layout where I can swipe the layout from left(edge) to right to reveal the main activity underneath.

The transition I have in mind is like the one on Sync for Reddit:
https://gfycat.com/ShallowHonestBeaver

How do I implement this for my app? Thank you for any help..

Comment: Use one activity and multiple fragments, rather than multiple activities.

Comment: I have a navigation drawer with the MainActivity with a few fragments. If I implement Preference as a fragment, the Navigation drawer shows up.